# How do I abort HTTP connection with 404 error code

Tags: linux

My application connects to http server to download a number of files (one file at a time). Server intermittently returns `http 404` for valid file. This just happens in production and I don't have access to server.

I put retries in my application and now I want to write a testcase emulating the situation.

I read about `tcpkill`, cutter but those don't seem to serve the purpose.

I was also reading about `squid` (setting up proxy), iptables but they also don't seem to serve my purpose.

What I am looking for is, after 1000 http successful requests to the server, I should close 1001th http connection with error code 404. I am inclined towards some proxy but don't know if any proxy is that dynamic.

Can someone please suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how appropriate it is for a *test case*, but I didn't know of any existing solutions (although I'm pretty sure there's one out there — I just don't know where) and it seemed like an interesting problem so I wrote a little Python script to do it. It runs on Python 3 only, so make sure you've got that. (Python 2 is more common at the time of writing.)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Latest version at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16494059/200291
"""
Accept TCP connections, usually proxying to another address, but occasionally
responding with 404 Not Found.
"""

import socket
import select

DROP_DATA = b'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n\r\nnot found\r\n'
PROXY_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096


class Reactor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reactants = []

    def add_reactant(self, reactant):
        self.reactants.append(reactant)

    def remove_reactant(self, reactant):
        self.reactants.remove(reactant)

    def iterate(self):
        r, w, x = [], [], []
        for reactant in self.reactants[:]:
            reactant.modify(self, r, w, x)
        r, w, x = select.select(r, w, x)
        for reactant in self.reactants[:]:
            reactant.notify(self, r, w, x)

    def loop(self):
        while self.reactants:
            self.iterate()


class Acceptor(object):
    def __init__(self, socket, action):
        self.socket = socket
        self.action = action

    def modify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        r.append(self.socket)

    def notify(self, reactor, r, w, d):
        if self.socket in r:
            result = self.socket.accept()
            self.action(result)


class Dropper(object):
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket
        self.queued = DROP_DATA

    def modify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        w.append(self.socket)

    def notify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        if self.socket in w:
            if self.queued:
                written = self.socket.send(self.queued)
                self.queued = self.queued[written:]
            else:
                self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                self.socket.close()
                reactor.remove_reactant(self)


class Connector(object):
    def __init__(self, addr, done):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setblocking(False)
        self.socket.connect_ex(addr)
        self.done = done

    def modify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        w.append(self.socket)

    def notify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        if self.socket in w:
            self.socket.setblocking(True)
            reactor.remove_reactant(self)
            self.done(self.socket)


class SimplexProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, source, dest, done):
        self.source = source
        self.dest = dest
        self.buffer = b''
        self.want_shutdown = False
        self.done = done

    def modify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        if self.buffer or self.want_shutdown:
            w.append(self.dest)
        else:
            r.append(self.source)

    def notify(self, reactor, r, w, x):
        if self.source in r:
            read = self.source.recv(PROXY_BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not read:
                self.want_shutdown = True
            else:
                self.buffer += read
        if self.dest in w:
            if self.want_shutdown:
                self.dest.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
                reactor.remove_reactant(self)
            else:
                written = self.dest.send(self.buffer)
                self.buffer = self.buffer[written:]


def join_sockets(reactor, socket_1, socket_2):
    closed = 0

    def done():
        nonlocal closed
        closed += 1
        if closed >= 2:
            socket_1.close()
            socket_2.close()

    reactor.add_reactant(SimplexProxy(socket_1, socket_2, done))
    reactor.add_reactant(SimplexProxy(socket_2, socket_1, done))


def run_server(reactor, addr, action, backlog=5):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
    sock.bind(addr)
    sock.listen(backlog)
    reactor.add_reactant(Acceptor(sock, action))


def proxy_connect(reactor, our_socket, their_addr):
    def connected(their_socket):
        join_sockets(reactor, our_socket, their_socket)

    reactor.add_reactant(Connector(their_addr, connected))


def run_dropper(reactor, our_addr, their_addr, drop_freq):
    count = 0

    def action(accepted):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        sock, addr = accepted
        if count % drop_freq == 0:
            reactor.add_reactant(Dropper(sock))
        else:
            proxy_connect(reactor, sock, their_addr)

    run_server(reactor, our_addr, action)


def main():
    def parse_port(s):
        p = int(s)
        if not (0 <= p < 65536):
            raise ValueError("invalid port")
        return p

    def parse_natural(s):
        n = int(s)
        if n > 0:
            return n
        else:
            raise ValueError("must be a natural number")

    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--local-host', metavar='HOST',
                        default='0.0.0.0', help="address to listen on")
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--local-port', type=parse_port, metavar='PORT',
                        help="local port to listen on", required=True)
    parser.add_argument('remote_host', help="host to connect to")
    parser.add_argument('remote_port', type=parse_port,
                        help="port to connect to")
    parser.add_argument('-D', '--drop-frequency', type=parse_natural,
                        metavar='FREQ', help="how many requests per drop",
                        required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    def resolve(host, port):
        info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port,
                                  socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        return info[0][-1]

    local = resolve(args.local_host, args.local_port)
    remote = resolve(args.remote_host, args.remote_port)

    reactor = Reactor()
    run_dropper(reactor, local, remote, args.drop_frequency)

    try:
        reactor.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To use it to proxy `localhost:8000` to port `9000`, dropping every 5th connection, run it like this:

```
% ./dropproxy.py localhost 8000 -p 9000 -D 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your super fast response. This is very close to what I am looking for. I am going to test it.